# Elvis operator for computed values

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin we can use the Elvis operator `?:` like this:

```
val string: String = null ?: "something else"
```

But what if "something else" is the result of a computation, like

```
val string: String = null ?: {
    // do some comutations here
    "something else"
}
```

This won't compile as the right hand side of `?:` is a function `() => String` and not `String`.

I have a feeling that I need to use one of the function `takeIf`, `takeUnless` etc. but I don't get it.

Thanks

Comment: doesn't make something else a function call works?

Comment: It seems an odd (and ultimately redundant) choice to declare something as non-nullable (i.e. `String` as opposed to `String?`) and then assign null on the left of the elvis operator. Why not `val string: String = run { ... }`, or `val string: String get() = ...`, or `val string: String = let { ... }`?

Comment: The hardcoded `null` was a simplication of the problem description. In reality it's a variable that could be `null` (obviously)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `run`-function. It performs a computation and returns its result.

```kotlin
val string: String = null ?: run {
    // do some computations here
    "something else"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`run`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html):

```
val string = something ?: run {
    // you can write multiple lines of code here,
    // to compute a final result
    val x = foo()
    val y = bar(x)
    baz(x, y)
}
```

Alternatively, if this doesn't need to be inline, just extract a function:

```
val string = something ?: computeValue()
```

Comment: You can also do it via the `let` function, so my question is, what is the advantage of `run` over `let` and vice-versa?

Comment: @MatthewLayton How would you do this with `let`? `let` needs an expression to operate on. But here we are at the RHS of a `?:` - we don't have any expression to operate on.

Comment: this works for me: https://pl.kotl.in/VCg7ygq0X

Comment: @MatthewLayton Ah I see. Since you are inside a companion object, it is implicitly `this.let { ... }`. While using `let` this way is basically the same as `run`, IMO, using `let` this way is confusing. The [recommended usage](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html#function-selection) of `let` is to "introduce an expression as a variable in local scope".

Comment: @MatthewLayton, Semantically, when you use `run` without calling it on anything, `this` is the same both inside and outside` the lambda. It truly behaves like nothing more than a way to bundle some code together inside some braces for code organization. On the other hand, if you use `let` without calling in on some subject, it's being called on the outer class, so now you have a weird lambda where there's a redundant `it` that's the same as `this`. `run` also has a receiverless overload so you don't even have to think about whether it's available for use anywhere--it works outside classes.

Comment: @Tenfour04 and Sweeper Thank you for the explanations. That's useful to know :)